# Raspberry Pi not working red light

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I bought a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ 2 weeks back, and did a small project related to weather monitoring. After that I wanted to check the led blinking with the Raspberry, and tried the connection. I want to check whether the led was working or not, so i put the led pins with 5v pin and gnd pin (for checking purpose) and suddenly, the system went off and not even booting. I suspect some hardware problem.
Can anyone help me please??

Comment: What LED was is? Which PINs did you use? What software is on the Raspberry Pi? Did you try unplug everything and boot again?

Comment: 1) Need more information, what did you shortened GPIO pins? 2) Does it do anything? Screen output? If doesn't do anything at all, then I expect you shortened 5V to ground, then maybe polyfuse or voltage regulator is gone. Fuse is next to power input on other side of the board on Pi 3B, please check schematics on 3B+. Supply power to RPI and test voltages with multimeter.

Answer (score 0):

LED was about 5v (I suppose), didn't use a 1k ohm resistor (I have very little idea about electronics)
Used RPi Pin 2(5v) and 6(gnd) to check LED (directly)
No screen output (image not booting).
Image was Rasbian with April 2018 Update

I'll check the schematics.